# Unir una consulta sql server para imprimir un reporte en c#

Tags: sql-server

Tengo esta tabla, la cual el campo de nombre de concepto es el id de otra tabla, pero requiero realizar una consulta donde en lugar de mostrarme el id me muestre el Nombre de concepto de la otra tabla.

```
select 
  IdFormulacion, 
  NombreConcepto,
  precio,
  cantidad, 
  total,
  Nota 
from Formulacion
```

Pensaba realizarlo de la siguiente manera, como se podra ver la otra tabla es una que se llama `Concepto_Gastos`, tambien hay otra tabla en la cual tiene nombres de concepto que no encontrara en esta de concepto gastos, como puedo solucionar esto, que esos id me los busque en las dos tablas y en lugar de mostrarme el id en la consulta me muestre el nombre de un concepto, lo necesito para realizar un procedimiento almacenado e imprimirla consulta en un *crystalReports* c#.

En la consulta de abajo me revuelve los campos, y no muestra todos, como que se confunde.

```
select 
  Concepto_Gastos.
  NombreConcepto,
  precio,
  cantidad, 
  total,
  Nota 
from Formulacion 
Inner join[Concepto_Gastos] on Formulacion.IdFormulacion = [Concepto_Gastos].idConceptoGastos
```

Comment: puedes mostrar los errores que te salen al ejecutar las consultas por favor @Jose Hernandez

Comment: @jeanpitx no hay errores lo que pasa es que esa tabla de Concepto_Gastos tiene muchos registros y al momento de ejecutar la consulta me los revuelve y me cambia los conceptos, lo hago con pocos registros en la tabla de formulacion y me lo hace correctamente.

Comment: has probado hacerlo sin inner join con el where: `Select * from Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
Where T1.ID = T2.ID`